# Blurry image with new VGA Cable

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vga

I have a Samsung TV Monitor, which I connect to my Dell Laptop through the VGA cable that came with the monitor. So far, no problem with that.

A few days ago I bought a new VGA Cable since I usually connect my laptop to my College's projector. However, when I use my brand-new VGA Cable with the same laptop on the same monitor I get a blurry image.

So... is it possible my new cable is just damaged, or there's a setting I need to try to get rid of the blurriness? Or maybe I just bought a wrong type of cable?

UPDATE:
I try the same monitor, using the new cable with another Laptop and it worked fine. Maybe some configuration is missing in my latop. By the way, I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: Is the pc output, and the TV set to the TV's native resolutions?

Comment: What I always do is change source to PC. I didn't do something else on the monitor.

Comment: Ahh, check that. LCD monitors look horrible if you run the wrong resolution.

Comment: What happens if you use the new cable for projector? If it works, I would keep that and use the old cable for TV.

Comment: One thing is weird and I am not sure why, some cables have a pin missing, and only have 14. I have seen pics on the net and it is the same pin. I have one of these cables and all monitors that I use with it are blurry. Do not EVER buy one with the missing pin! It should have all 15.

Answer (score 5):

VGA is an analog standard and subject to distortions of this nature if there is a quality problem with the wiring or connector, or the cable is too long.

If your laptop has a DVI, HDMI, or DisplayPort port, try connecting that (with the appropriate adapter if needed) to your TV's HDMI input.

Comment: As far as my experience, the VGA monitors are perfectly fine. Just make sure you do not have that missing pin (seen others on the internet with exact same pin missing).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that one of the pins is damaged.  Check to make sure none of the pins are bent.  If none of the pins are bent, I would try swapping the cable, and see if it has blurred images on other devices as well.

Comment: No pins are bent :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but tons of people still use VGA, especially with those lovely old XP PCs (great for playing old boxed games!) Took me a while to work it out but, some VGA cables come with a pin missing. It should be 15 pins.

If you buy a VGA cable (especially an old second hand one), make sure it has ALL 15 pins! If it does not have all 15 then any (probably newer) monitor you use it on will have a slight blur, which is annoying.